# Convert date format from 'm/d/yyyy' to 'yyyy-mm-dd' in a tsv file using a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, date, format

I have a column with a list of dates in a spreadsheet (.tsv) (some cells are blank) like that :
6/30/1988
 
1/2/2000
etc. ...

and I want a file.tsv with a list of dates in a column (keeping the blank cells, because it is for an export in a databases and I need the blank cells for my joints) :
1988-06-30

2000-01-02
etc. ...

I have done some research but as I am a beginner, I don t manage to do it.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `date` command:

```
$ date -d 6/30/1988 +%F
1988-06-30
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bash/korn shell solution that does not use external programs:

```
while IFS='/' read dd mm yyyy
do
    printf "%04d-%02d-%02d\n" $yyyy $mm $dd    
done < filename
```

Setting IFS separates the values around that character.